# how to can i access a variable declared in a public method inorder to use it in a private method

Tags: c#, excel

Am building an app that imports excel data into sql database but am having trouble with importing excel data from excel sheets with different file names other than the usual

> Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet*

So i thought i would try to read the sheet name from combo box but am not able to access the variables declared in a public method from a private method.

```
public void OpenFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
        od.Filter = "Excell|*.xls;*.xlsx;";
        DialogResult dr = od.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.Abort)
            return;
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(od.FileName))

        {
            //This is the variable am trying to access
            string file = od.FileName.ToString();
            OleDbcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + od.FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

            OleDbcon.Open();

            DataTable dt = OleDbcon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            OleDbcon.Close();

            cbosheet.Items.Clear();




            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)

            {

                String sheetName = dt.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                sheetName = sheetName.Replace(@"'", "");
                sheetName = sheetName.Replace("$", "");

                cbosheet.Items.Add(sheetName);

            }

        }

    }
```

Am trying to use the variable ***file*** in this method

```
private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       bulkcopy(text);

    }
```

Which will be used here

```
  public void bulkcopy(string excelFilePath)
    {
        string ssqltable = "Member";
        string myexceldataquery = "select [Employer Number],[Employer Name],[CODE],[No_of Employees],[VALUE],[Last month contributed for] from [" + cbosheet.Text + "$]";
        try
        {
            string excelconn = @"provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + excelFilePath +
            ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 12.0;hdr=yes;\"";
 ...
```

Comment: Read about variable scope: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: You need to make that variable a private data member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make file a `public` property:

```
public string CurrentFile { get; set; }
```

Then in your code:

```
//This is the variable am trying to access
CurrentFile = od.FileName.ToString();
```

and:

```
private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bulkcopy(CurrentFile);
}
```